# RoR - optionally filling form fields based on external data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently started with Rails, making some good progress but hit another snag now.

I have a form that users should fill out manually. An example would be something like a human resources pages where one can enter name, address, phone number of an employee.

What I would want to do is have another field "remote_id" that is optional and when filled out, will do a REST call to a remote resource to retrieve name/address/phone number and fill out the form on the fly but not immediately submit it. A time saver, if you will.

And I have no clear idea of what that would entail in terms of form filling (the controller action for the remote call is probably not a problem), but it seems to go beyond what rails will do "out of the box". JQuery, AJX, something else? A pointer would be really appreciated!

Cheers,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you need to check out for is the url of the remote resource and possible need to authenticate your request before having access to the resource. You might then make an ajax request to the resource. Using jQuery

```
$("remote_id").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax("http://externalresourceurl.com", {
      success: function(data) {
         // fill each form field with corresponding item in the data object
         $('#first_name').html($(data).first_name);
         ...
      },
      error: function() {
         $('#notification-bar').text('An error occurred');
      }
    }
 );
});
```